# inputfield value not changing

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="MyContactDemoController" showHeader="false" >
   <head>
      <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
      <apex:slds />
   </head>
   <div class="slds-scope" >
      <apex:form >
         <div class="slds-form--stacked slds-p-around--medium slds-m-bottom--x-small" style="width:20%;">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
               <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-form-element__label">First Name</apex:outputLabel>
               <apex:inputField value="{!con.FirstName}" styleClass="slds-form-element__control slds-input"  style="{!IF(con.FirstName =='', 'background-color:red;color:blue', 'background-color:blue;color:red')}>"  />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
               <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-form-element__label">Last Name</apex:outputLabel>
               <apex:inputField value="{!con.LastName}" styleClass="slds-form-element__control slds-input" />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
               <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-form-element__label">Email</apex:outputLabel>
               <apex:inputField value="{!con.Email}" styleClass="slds-form-element__control slds-input"    />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element">
               <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-form-element__label">Phone</apex:outputLabel>
               <apex:inputField value="{!con.Phone}" styleClass="slds-form-element__control slds-input"    />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="slds-button-group " role="group">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral " style="margin-left: 151px;"/>
         </div>
      </apex:form>
   </div>
</apex:page>
```

/////////////
On line 11 the colour of inputfield is not changing on changing FirstName value

Answer (score 2):

As @david Said You can use the javascript call with Event functions (onchange) in the input.

> As you mentioned in previous edit

You are using `<apex:inputfield>` So you can't just use `getElementById('id1').value` and get input Value.

Instead, Access with `$component` Followed by `Form-Id` and then `InputFied-Id` (add the path the Field)

```
<script>
   function changeColor(){
   debugger;
       var inputValue = document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.InputFld}').value;
       if(inputValue!= ''){
           document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.InputFld}').style.color = 'red';
           document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.InputFld}').style.background = 'blue';
       }else{            
           document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.InputFld}').style.background = 'red';
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: But when I making the input field field empty then it is not working.

Comment: Add the else part in your script with an appropriate color. Check the Code

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce bindings don't provide that kind of instant feedback, like you might get in a Lightning component. Visualforce expressions, like

```
{!IF(con.FirstName =='', 'background-color:red;color:blue', 'background-color:blue;color:red')}
```

are evaluated only during server-side rendering. If you want "live" reactions in your Visualforce code, you need to either

- Use client-side JavaScript to update the style on this element.
- Perform a server round-trip and partial page rerender (using the `rerender` attribute on, for example, an `<apex:actionFunction>` component), where the rerender includes the element whose Visualforce expression needs to be reevaluated.

Comment: I have updated my code with onchange javascript event but still it is not working.

Comment: That's really a different question. I'd prefer if you left the original content of your answer in place, since my answer now makes no sense, and open a new question for other issues.

Comment: Edit the question and add the old content above this new content.